# date calculation: add n days

Tags: calendar

Continues for topic: [Add (n) days to variable date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318006/add-n-days-to-variable-date)

But i want to use ShootDate like variable and other format:

26/10/2019 + 15

14/11/2019 + 30

05/03/2020 + 45

Please help with macro.

Thank a lot

Minimal coding:

```
 \documentclass[10p]{article}
    \usepackage[calc,datesep=/]{datetime2}
     \DTMsavedate{ShootDate}{2016-05-20}
    \newcommand{\PaymentTurnAroundDays}{45}
    \newcount\daycount
    \newcommand{\dueDate}[1]{%
        \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{ShootDate}{#1}\daycount
       \DTMsavejulianday{ShootDate}{\number\daycount}
       \DTMusedate{ShootDate}
    }

    \begin{document}

    Payment will be made by \dueDate{\PaymentTurnAroundDays} (within {\PaymentTurnAroundDays} of the day of the event(s)).

26/10/2019 + 15 day = ?

14/11/2019 + 30 day = ?

05/03/2020 + 45 day = ?
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what input you'd like to produce what output. Right now, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @cfr i updated my question. i want to calculate: 26/10/2019 + 15 day = ?, 14/11/2019 + 30 day = ?, 05/03/2020 + 45 day = ? with macro. Thanks

Comment: So why can't you do it with the answers to your other question e.g. the one using `datenumber`? That package does exactly what you say you want to do.

Comment: @cfr i give example with package datenumber, but you can change and use other package. thanks

Comment: What I mean is: why doesn't something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318009 do what you need? Turn the date into a number, add what you need and turn the result back into a date.

Comment: @cfr in this link, ShootDate is fix, i want shootdate like variable. thanks

Comment: But you can keep changing it, can't you?

Comment: i can't do it. I want to change \DTMsavedate{ShootDate}{2016-05-20} to variable ...

Comment: What do you mean by a 'variable'? LaTeX3 has a concept of variables, but that's not relevant here. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Best guess at what you want:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[calc,datesep=/]{datetime2}
\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\DueDate}[2]{%
  \DTMsavedate{ShootDate}{#1}%
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{ShootDate}{#2}\daycount
  \DTMsavejulianday{ShootDate}{\number\daycount}%
  \DTMusedate{ShootDate}%
}

\begin{document}

26/10/2019 + 15 day = \DueDate{2019-10-26}{15}

14/11/2019 + 30 day = \DueDate{2019-11-14}{30}

05/03/2020 + 45 day = \DueDate{2020-03-05}{45}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note this doesn't include any variables.

### Quick version for inverted dates with forward slashes.

> *Note that I do NOT recommend this. I would stick to ISO format for input.*
>
> ***Caveat emptor ...***

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[calc,datesep=/]{datetime2}
\newcount\daycount
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DueDate}[2]{%
  \edef\tempa{\expandafter\date@aux#1\@nil}%
  \DTMsavedate{ShootDate}{\tempa}%
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{ShootDate}{#2}\daycount
  \DTMsavejulianday{ShootDate}{\number\daycount}%
  \DTMusedate{ShootDate}%
}
\newcommand*\dateaux{}
\def\date@aux#1/#2/#3\@nil{#3-#2-#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

26/10/2019 + 15 day = \DueDate{26/10/2019}{15}

14/11/2019 + 30 day = \DueDate{14/11/2019}{30}

05/03/2020 + 45 day = \DueDate{05/03/2020}{45}
\end{document}
```

Produces the same output as above. Note you will get nonsense error messages if you input something which doesn't match the specified format.

Comment: it's right that i want. Please change format \DueDate{2019-10-26} to \DueDate{26/10/2019} . Thanks

Comment: @latexforti I don't recommend it, but you can do something quick and nasty like the above. Alternatively, there's probably a package for it somewhere, but all the ones I know are concerned with the typeset format of dates, rather than the input. (You probably want one of those to adjust the output, but that's just a question of reading the docs of `datetime2` or whatever. I'm allergic to `datetime2`, so I won't even try to go there.)

Comment: Thank. can you create output format = Day/Month/Year.

Comment: @latexforti See previous comment ^^.

Comment: @latexforti It's the same as for `\today`. The output will follow whatever global style you tell `datetime2` to use for dates. Just don't ask me to tangle with `datetime2`. I'm using a locally-fixed copy of `datetime` because I could not understand how to do simple things with `datetime2`.