# Convert from Today's Date to Specified Date

Tags: date

I am just a few hours new to TeX and have been tasked to modify an existing template (tex) document for parsing.

I have this in an `cls` file that works fine to add `#1` days to today's date:

```
\newcommand*{\duedate}[1]{%
    \setdatetoday%
    \addtocounter{datenumber}{#1}%
    \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
    \datedate%
}
```

However, I need to change it to a base date `#2` I would pass in as an additional parameter, and then have it add `#1`.

I tried using `\date`, but it continues to pickup today's date.

```
\newcommand*{\duedate}[2]{%
    \date{#2}%
    \addtocounter{datenumber}{#1}%
    \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
    \datedate%
}
```

As well as `\setdate`.

However, the output is always today's date + `#1`.

If there is documentation to read on how to set a date, and add "days" to a date, please point me to it.  I'd be more than happy to read up on proper syntex (phun)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318006/add-n-days-to-variable-date might be related to your question.

Comment: @modnar it took some time to figure out, but I posted the hacked solution as an answer below.  it's not ideal though, because there's a conflict between `datanumber` in my `cls`, and this `datetime2` package.  So if there's a way to resolve my question with just the OP code, it would be preferred so I do not have to define the function in the answer below.

Comment: Can you please provide minimla code (MWE) which makes \duedate run? Don't want to try all sorts of missing packages ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After evaluating the link in @modnar's comment, this would work:

```tex
\usepackage[calc,en-US]{datetime2}
\newcommand{\dueDate}[2]{%
    \DTMsavedate{InvoiceDate}{#2}
    \newcount\daycount
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{InvoiceDate}{#1}\daycount
    \DTMsavejulianday{newDate}{\number\daycount}
    \DTMusedate{newDate}
 }
```

However, this produces a conflict between `datetime2` and `datenumber` in the `cls` file.

So the above code must live in the main `.tex` document at this time.